# Editing /etc/sudoers to manage sudo rights for users and groups

Tags: sudo

I made a group called "group1" and I want to give it all sudo rights only except "chmod, chown" commands.
How can I change below sentence to get through this?

Before applying change:

```
%group1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: You can't. What prevents them from copying `chmod` to `foo` and running `sudo foo 777`?

Comment: Like muru said, but even simpler someone who can use `sudo` can open a root shell and run any commands without restrictions in there.